# How to batch "touch" files in subfolder with data from parent folder

Tags: macos, unix, video, ffmpeg, terminal

I have a folder named "Video" on my Desktop and inside that folder are a bunch of .MTS video files. (00000.MTS, 00001.MTS, 00002.MTS etc...)

There is also a subfolder "H.265" (Video > H.265) which contains files (00000.mp4, 00001.mp4, 00002.mp4 etc...) which were made by converting the files from the parent folder. The problem is they don't contain the correct date created metadata.

I want to use the command

```
touch -r 00000.MTS 00000.mp4
touch -r 00001.MTS 00001.mp4
...
touch -r 000mn.MTS 000mn.mp4
```

to copy the date from the MTS to the mp4 file.

Is there a way I could write a for loop or something to do this for every single file?

I am using MacOS Mojave.

Comment: `for f in *.mp4; do touch .. -r file $f` is a start, but you really want a `find ... --exec touch ...` solution. There are a million Q/A for `find`, so look at a few,  consult `man find` edit your Q to show your best attempt to solve the problem. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this

```
cd ~/Desktop/Video
for v in *.mp4 
do
    vn=`basename $v .mp4`
    touch -r "H.265/$vn.MTS" $v
done
```